# moving a div according to mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create and effect where you have a vertical  list, and when you hover it with your mouse, a separate "cursor" div should travel up and down vertically along this list, horizontally aligned with your pointer.

I am using this code:

```
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
   mouseY = e.pageY;
   mouseX = e.pageX;
   translateY = 'translateY(' + mouseY + 'px)';
   translateX = 'translateX(' + mouseX + 'px)';
});
```

Then with jQuery:

```
$(".sidebarnav").mouseover(function(){
  $('.sidebarnav .cursor').css({'transform': translateY});
});
```

All this kind of work, but the cursor div does not perfectly align with my mouse pointer. It does if you move real slow and with precision, but it doesn't if you move a bit faster. Is there any technical reason to this lack of precision, or is my code just wrong?

Here is a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/txks3wtj/

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net showing the exact issue. It's hard to visualise without seeing your HTML.

Comment: Agree with @RoryMcCrossan also your call to `translateY` would for example with a `mouseY` value of say 100 resolve to `translateY(100px);` which would be wrong as `100px` is a string and would need to be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: You may also have more luck with an absolutely positioned div using the CSS properties of `top, left, right...` etc.

Answer (score 1):

A fiddle would definitely help. But if I understand your code correctly I believe you can't just update the `.cursor`'s position on `mouseover` of the `.sidebarnav` - instead you need to update its position on `mousemove` ie all the time.

Since you don't want the cursor to move when *not* hovering the sidebar you'd need to keep track of whether or not it is hovered. Something like:

```
var isOver = false;

$('.sidebarnav').mouseover(function () {
    isOver = true;
}).mouseout(function () {
    isOver = false;
});

$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
    mouseY = e.pageY;
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    translateY = 'translateY(' + mouseY + 'px)';
    translateX = 'translateX(' + mouseX + 'px)';

    if (isOver) {
        $('.sidebarnav .cursor').css({'transform': translateY});
    }
});
```

Untested.

Edit: It would increase performance if you cached your queries as well;

```
var sidebar = $('.sidebarnav');
var cursor = sidebar.find('.cursor');
```

Edit2: You may have better results with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` too I think. I think over/out triggers as soon as you hover a child of the element as well.